# creating setup c#

Tags: c#-4.0, setup-project

I want to make setup in such a way there are two radio button in my setup that will ask full installation or custom install. IN full intallation this include all folders but in customs installlation 1 or 2folder not installed in Computer.....I have made setup of Full Installation but iam not able to make custom installation. so please help me to make setup which ask custom or full installation. for example Ms office ask full or custom installation if we tick custom then we are to install software which we want instead of Full

Answer (score 0):

Check the section 7) Useful Custom Action Example: Configuring Database Connection String
in the link
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/06/15/tip-trick-creating-packaged-asp-net-setup-programs-with-vs-2005.aspx

You should be able to create custom UI with two option buttons for Custom and Full installation.

Have your own [Installer.cs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer.aspx) file where you can get the user choice and copy the required folders based on user selection.