# How to create a custom action for VS 2010 setup program using DialogBox response

Tags: c#, visual-studio, registry, windows-installer, installation

I'm creating a setup program for an application that will require the user to choose between three setup options. I would like to take the result of the user input and write to the registry, so that the application can read this value at run-time. From what I've read so far I've been able to create the custom dialog with radio buttons, but what I haven't been able to find is how to take the result of the user's selection and then run a custom action which will write the result to the registry. I assume I can write a small script or executable which I can launch from the custom action by adding this script or exe by adding it to the application folder, but how do I get the value selected to be passed to this script or exe?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: The result of selecting a radio button is put in a property. Just store this property into a registry entry using regular registry entries. That's more reliable, more msi-way and does not require a custom action. (Avoid using custom action where the problem can be solved without using them.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe those links will help you:

[RadioButtons User Interface Dialog Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/taa17f7s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) 
[How to: Set Conditional Installation Based on User Choices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9x23561f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) 
[creating setup c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9849214/creating-setup-c-sharp)

My two cents: I think you may consider using another suite to create your installation, like [Installshield](http://www.installshield.com/). The VS 2010 setup program is, **IMHO**, not a good setup program.